# My code to capture the submit button on a form works but am I doing it correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form and some JavaScript code below it.  Everything works.  But what bothers me is that while everything else is in a function, the way I capture the submit button is not in a function.

So am I doing this correctly?

My form:

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/cgi-bin/prl.pl">
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Pick a country" autofocus>
<input id="113" type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

The top of my scripts:

```
<script>

var form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) 
{
  //////insert code to validate that 
  //////specific data is in my form

  e.preventDefault();
});

function setFocusToInput()
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("myInput");
    textbox.focus();
}

function autocomplete(inp, arr) 
{
  var currentFocus;
```

Comment: Without the knowledge of your objective, it is hard for others to tell you are doing right or wrong

Comment: I would simply like a JavaScript function to validate the HTML form when submit is clicked.  I just can't tell if the way I am doing it is the proper way.  Everything else has function that are called, but not the submit button.

Comment: so you want to validate your form on submit  ? right?

Comment: @AnandhukrishnaVR    Correct, but specific validation.  More than just "is a specific field filled."   I want to compare the data in an input to an array then either stop the submit or let it continue.

Comment: give that array! use validatorjs

Comment: And what about reading a documentation ?? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with inconsistency in javascript, but if you like it, 
you can do something like this:

```
function validateForm(ev){
    // do some validation
    var valid = false;
    if (!valid){
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
}

var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
```

notice there is no `()` when attaching the event handler

Comment: This is what I was looking for, it seems much cleaner if not at least more proper.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/cgi-bin/prl.pl" id="my-form"> 
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Pick a country" autofocus>
<input id="113" type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>

function processForm(e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

        /* do what you want with the form */

        // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
        return false;
    }

    var form = document.getElementById('my-form');
    if (form.attachEvent) {
        form.attachEvent("submit", processForm);
    } else {
        form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing wrong with you code, but if you really want to make it a function, you can add `onSubmit` to `<form>`, and write a JS function to process it. something like this:

HTML:
`<form onsubmit="process()">...</form>`

JS:
`function process() {}`